# Group by day in django admin?

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I need to group and count events by day in the django admin.

Here's my current admin queryset:

```
class TransactionLogAdmin(ExportMixin, OrganizationRestrictedAdmin):

    list_display = ['get_type_count', 'get_count']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return TransactionLog.objects.all().extra(
            select={'day': 'date( date_created )'}).values('datetime')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
return TransactionLog.objects.all().extra(
        select={'day': 'date( date_created )'}).values('datetime')
```

you have get_queryset method in the admin. As the name suggests, that method is expected to return a queryset. But you are returning a dictionary here. Remove the call to values()

When over riding get_queryset, it's always a good idea to call the method in the superclass and make modifications to it instead of making a new queryset of your own.

Comment: Well, that is an identification of the problem, but not a solution.