# How to group by in a query for the Django admin serach?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have a model called Task. The user shall search a specific search in the django admin area. So I implement the method:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
```

in `class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):`
I define a queryset in a complicated way. But that works. I now have a wounderful queryset resulting in a nearly perfect SQL statement. There is just one thing missing. I would love to add a GROUP BY at the end. But how? I tried several things:

The starting point:

```
[...]
queryset = self.model.objects.filter(joinedQ)
```

**Django aggregation:**

.values.aggregate() results normally in a group by, but I can't use .values for this query because django admin does not expect a dict as result. See: [Group by day in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311659/group-by-day-in-django-admin)

**using the hidden group_by attribute of the query:**

```
queryset.query.group_by = ["product"]
queryset = QuerySet(query=queryset.query, model=Task)
```

Does not work. The resulting query has all columns in group by, not only the product column like I specified. So it does not group anything.

**Query to string and than manually adding the GROUP BY**

```
string_query = str(queryset.query)
string_query += 'GROUP BY "main_task"."product", "main_task"."version"'
queryset = Task.objects.raw(string_query)
```

This results in the correct query what will find the correct results, but I get an exeption:
AttributeError: 'RawQuery' object has no attribute 'order_by'

**using .distinct("product")**

Does work, but only in PostgreSQL backends. Which I don't have.

So I tried a lot, but everything does not work. I am currently using a sqlite backend. Sqlite can easily execute a query like I need, but how to get django doing it?

Comment: There could be a way to do it in Django but it's hard to say without knowing your models and which values you want to aggregate. Can you note add `ORDER BY` to your raw SQL?

Comment: I can add ORDER BY, but that does not give the object the attribute 'order_by'.